# Create a Bash script which will print a message based upon which day of the week it is (eg. 'Happy hump day' for Wedensday, 'TGIF' for Friday etc)

Tags: bash, scripting, date

Create a Bash script which will print a message based upon which day of the week it is (eg. 'Happy hump day' for Wedensday, 'TGIF' for Friday etc).
How to print a message of the days of the week on a bash script?

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Consider accepting the most helpful answer to your question (rather than leaving a "thank you" comment, even though that's nice of you).  Doing so will mark the issue as resolved, and it will also increase your chances of getting help in the future. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Since you haven't accepted any of the answers, I must assume that you've run into some issue with  your code and that none of the answers are answering the question.  Since it's unclear what your issue is, I'm closing your question as "unclear".

Answer (score 3):

The current day of the week may be had as an integer between 1 and 7 (1 is Monday), with

```bsh
printf -v weekday '%(%u)T' -1
```

assuming you are running `bash` release 4.2 or later.

To assign a different message depending on this number, and print it:

```bsh
case $weekday in
    3) message='Happy hump day' ;;
    5) message='TGIF' ;;
    *) message='Some default message'
esac

printf 'Message of the day: %s\n' "$message"
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare an array of messages, then use the message that corresponds to the actual day of week. `date +%w` returns a number 0 .. 6 (where 0 corresponds to Sunday) that you can use as the index.

```
#! /bin/bash
messages=(Sunday
          IFHM
          Tuesday
          'Happy hump day!'
          Thursday
          TGIF
          Saturday)

echo "${messages[$(date +%w)]}"
```